# Are any game modes locked behind DLC?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there any DLC requirement to playing any of the game modes? For example, do I need any specific DLC to play the Scavenger game mode? Does the base game allow me to play **ANY** game mode?

I'm not referring to playing on a specific map, just a specific mode.

Comment: I am playing on the XBOX 360 but answers for any platform are welcome

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I recall the "Close quarters" DLC bringing a new gamemode that wasn't available before. Since this gamemode only existed on the maps added in CQ you essentially needed the CQ DLC to play that gamemode.

Comment: I want to say that Tank Superiority is also part of one, but IDK. They don't really specify. If there are any, they haven't been worth playing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, nowadays basic game is pretty much useless in terms of playing multiplayer. Maps are tied to modes, by the way. Of course you can always play in servers using stock, but the selection is quite reduced. That's why EA has given stock BF3 for free or almost free several times. Most servers rotate using some of the maps from DLC's, so you can get kicked because lacking such DLC. The server description always states the required DLC however. Here are some specifics.

**Basic Game**

- [Conquest](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Conquest)
- [Rush](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Rush)
- [Team Deathmatch](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Team_Deathmatch)
- [Squad Deathmatch](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Squad_Deathmatch)
- [Squad Rush](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Squad_Rush)
- [Co-op](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Co-op)

**Back to Karkand**

- [Conquest Assault](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Conquest#Conquest_Assault)

**Close Quarters**

- [Conquest Domination](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Domination)
- [Gun Master](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Gun_Master)
- [Team Deathmatch Close Quarters](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Team_Deathmatch#Team_Deathmatch_Close_Quarters)

**Aftermath**

- [Scavenger](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Scavenger)
- [Gun Master](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Gun_Master)

**Armored Kill**

- [Tank Superiority](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Tank_Superiority)

**End Game**

- [Capture the Flag](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_the_Flag)
- [Air Superiority](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Air_Superiority)

Comment: It's kind of sad when only 40% of the game modes are in the basic game...

Comment: @DangerZone Welcome to EA Business Model, we hope you like your stay.