# What multiplayer modes are available in the DLC and what do they do?

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to know if it is worth buying the Battlefield 3 DLCs.

What DLCs are available?

What modes do they add?

Do the DLCs add any new single player campaigns?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254000/101016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Available DLCs

According to [battlefield.com](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield3/1/all-bf3-dlc-expansion-packs), the available DLCs are:

1. [Back to Karkand](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Back_to_Karkand)
2. [Close Quarters](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Close_Quarters)
3. [Armored Kill](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Armored_Kill)
4. [Aftermath](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Aftermath)
5. [End Game](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/End_Game)

*(links redirect to IGN's Battlefield 3 Wiki)*

---

### What They Add

Using IGN's [Battlefield 3 Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/DLC_%26_Expansions), I was able to confirm what each DLC contributed to the overall game as far as modes and items available.

**Back to Karkand** adds the [Conquest Assault](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Conquest_Assault) game mode as well as 4 maps brought over from previous Battlefield games, 3 vehicles, and 10 weapons.

**Close Quarters** adds the [Gun Master](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Gun_Master) and [Conquest Domination](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Conquest_Domination) modes as well as 4 new maps, 10 weapons, and new Dog Tags.

**Armored Kill** adds the [Tank Superiority](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Tank_Superiority) game mode as well as 4 new maps, 6 vehicles, and 5 new assignments.

**Aftermath** adds the [Scavenger](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Scavenger?objectid=82318) game mode as well as 4 new maps, 2 weapons, 3 vehicles, and some new assignments.

**End Game** adds the [Capture the Flag](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Capture_the_Flag) and [Air Superiority](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Air_Superiority) game modes as well as 4 new maps, 4 vehicles, and some new assignments.